# Identify quotient group

Tags: group-theory

Identify quotient group $\mathbb R^*/\mathbb R^+$ where $\mathbb R^*$ is multiplicative group of non zero reals and $\mathbb R^+$ denotes subgroup of positive real numbers. I'm using first isomorphism theorem. We will define a map which is on to homomorphism  and its kernel will be $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Could you make a nice and readable sentence out of that? This isn't twitter, there's plenty of space...

Comment: It is the map $C\to C/P$ prescribed by $r\mapsto rP$.

Answer (score 4):

Define $f:\mathbb R^*\rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ by

$f(x)=1 ;x>0$ 
and $f(x)=-1;x<0$

Answer (score -1):

Define surjective Homomorphism by $\varphi:(\mathbb{C}^*,.)\to (S^1,.) , z\mapsto{z\over |z|}$, so Kernel is $(\mathbb{R}^+,.)$

so the required group is $S^1$ i.e circle group $=\{z\in\mathbb{C}^*:|z|=1\}$

Comment: You have misread the question.